# Spring boot websockets listener add parameter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

I am implementing a chat room with webscoket by Spring boot

This is the code

ChatMessage.Class

```
public class ChatMessage {
    private MessageType type;
    private String content;
    private String sender;

    public enum MessageType {
        CHAT,
        JOIN,
        LEAVE
    }

    public MessageType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(MessageType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

}
```

My WebSocketConfig.Class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

WebSocketListener.Class

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketConnectListener(SessionConnectedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received a new web socket connection");
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

        String username = (String) headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get("username");
        if (username != null) {

            ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
            chatMessage.setType(ChatMessage.MessageType.LEAVE);
            chatMessage.setSender(username);
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

ChatController:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {


    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage/{room}")
    public void sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage, @DestinationVariable String room) {
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public/"+room, chatMessage);
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser/{room}")
    public void addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                               SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor, @DestinationVariable String room) {
        // Add username in web socket session
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public/"+room, chatMessage);
    }
}
```

My Index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spring Boot WebSocket Chat Application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <h2>Sorry! Your browser doesn't support Javascript</h2>
</noscript>

<div id="username-page">
    <div class="username-page-container">
        <h1 class="title">Type your username</h1>
        <form id="usernameForm" name="usernameForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="room_num" placeholder="RoomNum" autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="accent username-submit">Start Chatting</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="chat-page" class="hidden">
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-header">
            <h2>Spring WebSocket Chat Demo</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="connecting">
            Connecting...
        </div>
        <ul id="messageArea">

        </ul>
        <form id="messageForm" name="messageForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group clearfix">
                    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Type a message..." autocomplete="off" class="form-control"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="primary">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/sockjs-client/1.1.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/stomp.js/2.3.3/stomp.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
    'use strict';

var usernamePage = document.querySelector('#username-page');
var chatPage = document.querySelector('#chat-page');
var usernameForm = document.querySelector('#usernameForm');
var messageForm = document.querySelector('#messageForm');
var messageInput = document.querySelector('#message');
var messageArea = document.querySelector('#messageArea');
var connectingElement = document.querySelector('.connecting');


var stompClient = null;
var username = null;
var room_num = null;

var colors = [
    '#2196F3', '#32c787', '#00BCD4', '#ff5652',
    '#ffc107', '#ff85af', '#FF9800', '#39bbb0'
];

function connect(event) {
    username = document.querySelector('#name').value.trim();
    room_num = document.querySelector('#room_num').value.trim();
    if(username) {
        usernamePage.classList.add('hidden');
        chatPage.classList.remove('hidden');

        var socket = new SockJS('/ws');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}


function onConnected() {
    // Subscribe to the Public Topic
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public/'+room_num, onMessageReceived);

    // Tell your username to the server
    stompClient.send("/app/chat.addUser/"+room_num,
        {},
        JSON.stringify({sender: username, type: 'JOIN'})
    );

    connectingElement.classList.add('hidden');
}


function onError(error) {
    connectingElement.textContent = 'Could not connect to WebSocket server. Please refresh this page to try again!';
    connectingElement.style.color = 'red';
}


function sendMessage(event) {
    var messageContent = messageInput.value.trim();
    if(messageContent && stompClient) {
        var chatMessage = {
            sender: username,
            content: messageInput.value,
            type: 'CHAT'
        };
        stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage/"+room_num, {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage));
        messageInput.value = '';
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}


function onMessageReceived(payload) {
    var message = JSON.parse(payload.body);

    var messageElement = document.createElement('li');

    if(message.type === 'JOIN') {
        messageElement.classList.add('event-message');
        message.content = message.sender + ' joined!';
    } else if (message.type === 'LEAVE') {
        messageElement.classList.add('event-message');
        message.content = message.sender + ' left!';
    } else {
        messageElement.classList.add('chat-message');

        var avatarElement = document.createElement('i');
        var avatarText = document.createTextNode(message.sender[0]);
        avatarElement.appendChild(avatarText);
        avatarElement.style['background-color'] = getAvatarColor(message.sender);

        messageElement.appendChild(avatarElement);

        var usernameElement = document.createElement('span');
        var usernameText = document.createTextNode(message.sender);
        usernameElement.appendChild(usernameText);
        messageElement.appendChild(usernameElement);
    }

    var textElement = document.createElement('p');
    var messageText = document.createTextNode(message.content);
    textElement.appendChild(messageText);

    messageElement.appendChild(textElement);

    messageArea.appendChild(messageElement);
    messageArea.scrollTop = messageArea.scrollHeight;
}


function getAvatarColor(messageSender) {
    var hash = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < messageSender.length; i++) {
        hash = 31 * hash + messageSender.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var index = Math.abs(hash % colors.length);
    return colors[index];
}

usernameForm.addEventListener('submit', connect, true)
messageForm.addEventListener('submit', sendMessage, true)
```

I want to realize that multiple chat rooms exist at the same time, So i do not use the @Sendto

I define a input room_num to indicate the number of the chat room

In js file, use `stompClient.send("/app/chat.sendMessage/"+room_num, {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage));` to send message.

In Controller, use `simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public/"+room, chatMessage);` receive message from different chatroom

But this way of stitching url will produce a lot hard code
Is there any good alternative?

When the user leaves the chat room， handleWebSocketDisconnectListener use `messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", chatMessage);` to notify users in a same chatroom, someone leave this room,

but the url should be /topic/public/room_num.
However, this is a DisconnectListener, It will listen for all closed connections，

I want to realize that when the user leaves a chat room, only notify the users in the same chat room that the user has left